# Scale page for different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a page which I use margins to place text at different parts of the page as shown below. The A, B, C etc. have been placed there using margin-left in CSS. These however move around depending on the zoom level and resolution of the screen showing them. How can I can place them in the current position so that they won't move around on different screens?

```
<div>
<div>
  <br>
  <span class="bigLeft">SECRET.</span>
  <span class="bigRight">FORM "F"</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="biggerCenter">COMBAT REPORT.</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="bigLeft">Sector Serial No.</span>
  <span class="bigCenterLettersA">(A)</span>
  <span class="bigContentRight"> J.1 </span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="bigLeft">Serial Number of Order Detailing Flight or Squadron to Patrol</span>
  <span class="bigCenterLettersB">(B)</span>
  <span class="bigContentRight"> NIL </span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="bigLeft">Date</span>
  <span class="bigCenterLettersC">(C)</span>
  <span class="bigContentRight">{{ decodeHTML(report_info.mission_hist_date) }} </span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="bigLeft">Flight, Squadron</span>
  <span class="bigCenterLettersD">(D)</span>
  <span class="bigContentRight">{{ flightStatus[report_details.flight] }}, {{ reportUnit.hist_unit_name }} ({{ reportUnit.hist_unit_code }})</span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="bigLeft">Number of Enemy Aircraft</span>
  <span class="bigCenterLettersE">(E)</span>
  <span class="bigContentRight"> {{ report_info.enemy_ac_number }} </span>
</div>
<br>
```

This is the CSS.

```
   <style scoped>

  .bigRight {
    float: right;
    font-size: large;
    margin-right: 8%;
  }

  .bigLeft {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 8%;
  }

  .bigCenterLettersA {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 48%;
  }

  .bigCenterLettersB {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 69.1%;
  }

  .bigCenterLettersC {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 57.3%;
  }

  .bigCenterLettersD {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 48.5%;
  }

  .bigCenterLettersE {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 41.8%;
  }

  .bigCenterLettersF {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 43.8%;
  }

  .bigCenterPersonnel {
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 39.3%;
  }

  .synopsisText {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
  }

  .biggerCenter {
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 40%;
  }

  .bigContentRight {
    font-size: large;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 2%;
  }

  .bigContentLeft {
    font-size: large;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }

  .bigContentCenter{
    font-size: large;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 19%;
  }


</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the height and width of an element you can set them to a fixed position in the page with

```css
.bigLeft {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 8vw;
}
```

That being said this isn't advised because it can become a huge mess.
Also another side note that this would require a fixed width page using the second method as well.

---

Another possibility would be to make the browser render in a set width no matter screen width.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920px">
```

Though again this isn't the nicest thing to do.

---

Personally i'd go with setting the width of the "page" to your desired width using `min-width` and `max-width` and then using `margin-left: 100px` etc to position your elements.

Using `position: relative` could also do the trick here.

Comment: Will that still not change when you zoom in or have a different resolution? I would think it would mess it up.

Comment: I think most options will do that, the 3rd option i've added using `min-width` and `max-width` or just `width` though this is a lot of moving elements around with px spacings

Comment: Could it work properly if I used a table type thing? Not sure how to though.

Comment: Sure you can use a table you can render it without borders, but you'd still need to use a set width and might need to push around some elements